# Virus Scan - Cannot Open Directory/File

Tags: antivirus

Using Ubuntu 19.4
When scanning with Sophos it scans nearly 80,000 files. However it comes up with an error message in the log saying " /snap " directory couldn't be opened ?
So what I do is scan that directory with ClamTK just to make sure there's nothing malicious.

Any ideas why it doesn't play ball with that directory ?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the Ask Ubuntu forums!

/snap is only accessible by the root user (the user you created in the Ubuntu installation) so if you are running a virus scan as a regular user it cannot access the directory. Try running the antivirus program through the terminal by running:

`sudo` and the antivirus name and remember, all letters are non-capital. Plus, the package name may be different from the program name. For Sophos, the package name should be `sophos` or `sophos-av` so you would run:

`sudo sophos` or you would run `sudo sophos-av`

As for if something malicious is in /snap, it is very unlikely. Snaps are tested before being added to the Store and also they are self-contained. They can't read nor write to anywhere outside their directory.

Comment: Great thank you !
I did put sudo before the scan command but no luck

Comment: Which place is most important to scan ?

Comment: @venomx home directory and downloads directory

Comment: @venomx windows related directories are the only you need to scan (so samba connections and wine). Scanning for linux virusses is a waste of time up to now. As soon as a virus hits our desktop(!) systems that is worth using a scanner for you will hear it 1st on all the news outlets. Cuz it will be BIG news when that happens.